# Commutator $[x_i,p_j/p]$ with $p=|\vec{p}|$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

I'm looking for the above commutator where I suppose $p=|\vec{p}|$. Using
$$[A,BC]=[A,B]C+B[A,C] \, ,$$
I came up with
$$[x_i,p_j p^{-1}]=[x_i,p_j]p^{-1} + p_j[x_i,p^{-1}] = i \delta_{ij} p^{-1} + p_j[x_i,p^{-1}] \tag{0}$$
where I used the canonical commutator $[x_i,p_j]=i\delta_{ij}$ (pre-factor is the imaginary unit). For the second commutator I have
$$0=[x_i,pp^{-1}]=[x_i,p]p^{-1}+p[x_i,p^{-1}]$$
$$\Rightarrow \qquad [x_i,p^{-1}]=-p^{-1}[x_i,p]p^{-1} \, , \tag{1}$$
which leaves me with
$$2ip_i=[x_i,p^2]=[x_i,p]p + p[x_i,p]$$
and now I'm stuck. I see that if $[x_i,p]=i p_i/p$, both sides work out, but it's not really a formal proof.

Is it really necessary to write for each component (for instance $i=1$) $$p=\sqrt{p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2}=\sqrt{p_2^2+p_3^2} \sqrt{1+\frac{p_1^2}{p_2^2+p_3^2}}=\sqrt{p_2^2+p_3^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k} \left( \frac{p_1^2}{p_2^2+p_3^2} \right)^k$$
and use the fact that
$$[x_1,p_2]=[x_1,p_3]=0 \\ 
[x_1,p_1^{2k}]=i2k\,p_1^{2k-1}=i\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}p_1}p_1^{2k} \, ?$$

This gives
$$[x_i,p]=i\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}p_i} p=i p_i/p \qquad \stackrel{(1)}{\Rightarrow} \qquad [x_i,p^{-1}]=-i p_i/p^3 \, .$$
Surely, I could have used the binomial expansion in (1) directly, but that's besides the point.

Are there other approaches, without relying on the series expansion?

Comment: You could use the fact that $1/p = \int_0^\infty t^{-1/2}\,e^{-t\,p^2}\,\mathrm d t$, but I suppose it is not that much better (but it treats better the case where $p_j$ is not invertible and unbounded I would believe)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical commutation relations $$[x_i, p_j]=i\delta_{ij} \tag{1} \label{eq1}$$ (valid on a suitable common domain for the components of the position and the momentum operator) imply $$[x_i, f(\vec{p})]= i \frac{\partial}{\partial p_j} f(\vec{p}), \tag{2} \label{eq2}$$ for a suitable differentiable  function $f$. (Remember that the position operator generates translations in momentum space and vice versa.)

The validity of \eqref{eq2} can easily seen by realizing \eqref{eq1} in the momentum representation with $x_i \to i \partial /\partial p_i$ and $p_j$ as a multiplication operator acting on momentum-space wave functions $\psi(\vec{p})$. Acting on $\psi(\vec{p})$, \eqref{eq2} becomes indeed $$[x_i, f(\vec{p})] \psi(\vec{p})=i \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} \left(f(\vec{p}) \psi(\vec{p})\right)- i f(\vec{p}) \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} \psi(\vec{p}) = i \frac{\partial  f(\vec{p})}{\partial p_i} \psi(\vec{p}). \tag{3} \label{eq3}$$ Note that the position-space representation (where $x_i$ acts as a multiplication operator on wave functions $\phi(\vec{x})$ and $p_i \to -i \partial/\partial x_i$) and the momentum-space representation are equivalent as they are connected a unitary mapping, the Fourier tranformation  $\mathcal{F}: L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with $$\mathcal{F}^{-1} x_i \mathcal{F} = i \partial/\partial p_i, \quad \mathcal{F}^{-1} (-i \partial/ \partial x_i) \mathcal{F} = p_i.$$ For showing \eqref{eq2}, the momentum-space representation turns out to be simply more convenient.

In your case, $f(\vec{p}) = p_j/|\vec{p}|$, one finds thus the result $$\left[x_i, \frac{p_j}{|\vec{p}|}\right]=i\left( \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|\vec{p}|}-\frac{p_i p_j}{|\vec{p}|^3} \right). \tag{4} \label{eq4}$$

Comment: I think your second equation it is merely what the question is asking about ... is there a simple proof of this fact without using functional calculus?

Comment: I shall extend my answer to clarify this point.

Comment: I was actually thinking about your second line, but then proving it I would be back at using a power series for $f$ or a Fourier-transform and then doing $[x_i,e^{ip_i t}]$ with integration variable $t$, or? I mean technically it boils down to proving your second equation, without relying on any series or transformation.

Comment: @Diger The position space representation and the momentum space representation are equivalent, connected by a unitary transformation (the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}: L^2(\mathbb{R)}\to L^2( \mathbb{R})$). Which one you choose is a matter of taste or convenience depending on the problem you want to solve. In any case, you do not need a power series expansion.

Comment: My QM is a bit rusty... So the definition of momentum space is only via FourierTransform in that $p$ acts on the Fourier Transform, like $x$ acts on the function in the position space?

Regarding the representation: I see that $x_i=i\partial_{p_i}$ satisfies the c.c.r.. Suppose there is another operator $y_i$ that satisfies the same c.c.r., then $[y_i-x_i,p_j] = 0$. That is $y_i=x_i+z_i$ for some operator $z_i$ that commutes with $p_j$. How would you deduce, that $z_i=0$?

Comment: @Diger Let's do this in *one* spatial dimension. Suppose, we have $[x,p]=i \mathbf{1}$. The operator $x^\prime = x+a \mathbf{1}$ ($a$ is a real constant) and $p$ still satisfy the canonical commutation relation $[x^\prime, p]= i \mathbf{1}$, as $a \mathbf{1}$ commutes with $p$.  The pairs $(x,p)$ and $(x^\prime, p)$ are related by the unitary transformation $U(a)=\exp(-i a P)$ generating a spatial  translation but leaving the momentum unaffected with $U(a)^{-1} x U(a)= x+a=x^\prime$ and $U(a)^{-1}pU(a)=p$. There are infinitely many ways to realize the ccr's, all connected by a unitary mapping.